# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'randomProperty' of undefined + Warning 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalSupply' of undefined
```

Alongside this warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function
```

In app.js I am getting data from the blockchain with useEffect, save it into an array called vaults with useState and display it with JSX.

The array vaults is shaped in this way

```
vaults = [{totalSupply: 0, totalBorrowed: 0, capUtilRate: 0}]
```

The error occurs when JSX tries to access vaults[0].totalSupply.

If I understood the problem right, this happens because on the first render vaults[0] is an empty object (undefined) and it breaks the app.
If this is correct, then how do I display data correctly?

This is the app.js:

```
  const [vaults, setVaults] = useState([]);
  async function loadBloackchainData(isMounted) {
    const web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/');
    const vault = new web3.eth.Contract(VaultABI, testnet.Vaults[0].address);
    const name = await vault.methods.symbol().call();
    const totalSupply = parseInt(await vault.methods.totalSupply().call());
    const totalBorrowed = parseInt(await vault.methods.vaultDebtVal().call());
    const capUtilRate = Number.isNaN(totalSupply / totalBorrowed) ? 0 : totalSupply / totalBorrowed;
    if (isMounted) {
      setVaults((prevVaults ) => ([
        ...prevVaults ,
        {
          totalSupply,
          totalBorrowed,
          capUtilRate,
        },
      ]));
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    loadBloackchainData(isMounted);
    // cleanup
    return () => (isMounted = false);
  }, []);

  return (
      <>
        <div>TotalSupply is: {vaults[0].totalSupply}</div>
        <div>TotalBorrowed is: {vaults[0].totalBorrowed}</div>
        <div>CapUtilRate is: {vaults[0].capUtilRate}</div>
      </>
    );
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalSupply' of undefined` is caused by the `vaults` initial state value being an empty array, so `vaults[0]` is undefined on the initial render. The second issue is unclear, seems the `ChildComponent` unexpectedly. Are you sure this is where the second error is referring to?

Comment: No, sorry I should have mentioned that. The error also occurs if I console.log vaults[0].totalSupply in the app.js.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive component code example then?

Comment: Yes, really sorry about that, my question was not formulated in a clear way. I refactor the question.

Comment: If you are only ever rendering the zero'th element then a null check would suffice, `vaults[0]?.totalSupply`, or you can apply some conditional rendering, `vaults.length && (.... access vaults[0] now ....)`.

Comment: I later will render a dynamic index of the array but vaults.length &&  works perfectly. This was just some basic that I completely forgot. Thank you again @DrewReese. If you want to write the answer I will accept it as right as you wrote me before  Bao Huynh Lam who also gave the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalSupply' of undefined` is caused by the `vaults` initial state value being an empty array, so `vaults[0]` is undefined on the initial render.

You can use null checks on the array elements being accessed:

```
return (
  <>
    <div>TotalSupply is: {vaults[0]?.totalSupply}</div>
    <div>TotalBorrowed is: {vaults[0]?.totalBorrowed}</div>
    <div>CapUtilRate is: {vaults[0]?.capUtilRate}</div>
  </>
);
```

Or apply conditional rendering on the `vaults` array length. All non-zero array lengths are considered truthy, while length 0 is falsey.

```
return vaults.length ? (
  <>
    <div>TotalSupply is: {vaults[0].totalSupply}</div>
    <div>TotalBorrowed is: {vaults[0].totalBorrowed}</div>
    <div>CapUtilRate is: {vaults[0].capUtilRate}</div>
  </>
) : null; // or fallback, etc...
```

If later you will be rendering dynamic `vaults` array content (I assume mapping to JSX) then I would suggest using the second method.

Answer (score 1):

As for the `TypeError`, it is to be noted that `useEffect` runs only **after rendering**. Therefore, on the first render, your `vaults` variable is initialized as an empty array. Therefore, the expression `vaults[0].totalSupply` did not succeed - because it is accessing index 0 of an empty array - thus yielding `undefined`.

The solution is doing a conditional rendering, or providing a default value through the OR pipe operator

Conditional rendering using ternary operator

```js
return (
  <>
    {vaults.length > 0 ? (
      <>
        <div>TotalSupply is: {vaults[0].totalSupply}</div>
        <div>TotalBorrowed is: {vaults[0].totalBorrowed}</div>
        <div>CapUtilRate is: {vaults[0].capUtilRate}</div>
      </>
    ) : (
      <div>
        "Empty vaults - Skeleton value wating for useEffect to
        fetch data"
      </div>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Default value style:

```js
return (
  <>
    <div>TotalSupply is: {vaults[0]?.totalSupply || "Default totalSupply"}</div>
    <div>
      TotalBorrowed is: {vaults[0]?.totalBorrowed || "Default totalBorrowed"}
    </div>
    <div>CapUtilRate is: {vaults[0].capUtilRate || "Deafult capUtilRate"}</div>
  </>
);
```